Why is the electric field proportional to the current density in the far-field?
When wanting to calculate the electric field generated by a laser pulse, I have found in this thesis(page 73) that, in the far-field:
$$E \propto \frac{\partial J}{\partial t}\tag{1}$$
where $E$ is the electric field and $J$ is the current density.
I have tried to reach this conclusion by manipulating the Maxwell equations, as follows:
$$ \nabla \times E = \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\tag{2}$$
$$\nabla \times B = \mu_0 ( J + \epsilon_o \frac{\partial E}{\partial t})\tag{3}$$
By taking the curl of equation 2, we reach equation 4 (below)
$$\nabla^2 E = \mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(J + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t})\tag{4}$$
I couldn't find anywhere that explained to me how to solve this equation to get to (1),
I don't understand this, is there anyway that this can be solved mathematically?

The thesis is 165 pages. Can you at least say on what page you found your Eq (1) so we don't have to read the whole thing? (At a very wild guess: In a picosecond pulse, there is likely not enough time for the mobile electrons to transfer energy to the lattice and thus obtain ohmic behavior)

Done. Thanks for noticing that, I thought I had put it there

I don't know the details of this, but you are not going in the right direction. In the thesis, they're relating the electric field in the far field of an emission source to the current at the point of emission. In Maxwell's equations the relation is between the field and the current at the same point in space. So there's no direct connection between the equation you are starting with (Maxwell) and the one you're trying to get (from the thesis).

This shouldn't be a surprise. For example, you also can't derive Ohm's Law from Maxwell's equations. Maxwell's equations tell you about how the EM field behaves, but they don't know anything about how materials behave. You have to work out from elsewhere how the field affects the material (and then possibly plug in the resulting $\varepsilon$, $\mu$, and $\mathbf{J}$ values into Maxwell's equations to see how that affects the field.

So mathematically it cannot be achieved unless we contextualise the material's interaction with the signal?

I don't know enough about THz emitters to even know where the equation comes from. But I am pretty sure it isn't derived from Maxwell. Did you follow up to ref [33] in the thesis?

By [Jefmenko equations][1]
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int \left[\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}\rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r) + \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^2}\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} \right] dV',
$$
In far field, $|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|\gg 1$, we can neglect first term. Without charges, the second term is null and we have
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) \approx- \int \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} dV',
$$
I can see how we can neglect the source shape and simplify this integral, but I can't see how we can get rid of this $r^{-1} $ dependence, since it's necessary to keep intensity $|\vec E|^2$ with $r^{-2}$ dependence. This is the far I could get, I hope it helps!
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations
